# Type Syntax error on token "MainActivity", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting the following error "Type Syntax error on token "MainActivity", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" and I am not sure what is causing the issue can somebody please help. I have marked where the rror is with *

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

 public void addListenerOnButton (MainActivity) *
 {

    //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
    button = (Button) findViewById(R+id/button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent openBrowser =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://www.vocationalfitness.co.uk"));
       startActivity(openBrowser);
      }

    });

}
```

Comment: You've missed out the parameter's name.

Comment: `public void addListenerOnButton (MainActivity) *` change that to `public void addListenerOnButton (MainActivity mainActivity)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the method parameters for `addListenerOnButton` you need to add parameter name or remove `MainActivity`.